# Why does my array from backend doesn't print in the frontend ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, submit

I have a simple 'Submit a post' project with 2 inputs (title and description) and a submit button.

Whenever I press submit, I send the title and description value to the backend where it it stored there in an array called submittedPosts. For example:

**Code in the backend:**

```
const submittedPosts = [ 
{
title: 'test',
description: 'test',
date: 'test'
   }
];
```

The problem is - I can't print ALL the array in the frontend to show the clients all the posts.

Things that I've tried but it did not work:

I've tried to get the array from the backend and assign it to the posts state, and then print it in the JSX as shown below:

**Code in the frontend:**

```
const loadAllPosts = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/posts");
    setPosts(res.data);
  };

//in JSX
<div>
    {posts}
</div>
```

I've also tried using map(), but I didn't do it correctly and got lost there...

I'd love to get a little help here.. Thanks.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  If you're not familiar with debugging your application, now is the time to start learning about that.  For example, you can use your browser's debugging tools to observe your AJAX requests/responses and observe specific runtime values of your variables.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `posts` is an array you have to map every element of it to JSX elements so it can be rendered.

Let's say you want an `h1` with the title, a `paragraph` with the description and a `span` with the date

```
<div>
    {posts.map((post)=>{
      return (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.description}</p>
          <span>{post.date}</span> 
        </div>
       )
     })}
</div>
```

You should also assign a `key` prop to every post, that's why I added `key={post.id}` despite your post structure not having it. You can assign the title as a key if you don't have unique id's for now but consider having unique id's

Comment: Absolute pro. Thank you for your answer. Problem is fixed :)